# Phase noise and frequency noise relationship

Tags: noise, phase

I want to know how calculate the frequency noise from phase noise.
More clearly calculation of frequency noise spectral density from phase noise spectral density.
Please explain deeply how the relationship came ( mathamatics).

Answer (score 5):

The relationship between Frequency Noise and Phase Noise is as follows:

$$S_f(f) = (f)^2S_{\phi}(f) \tag{1} \label{1}$$

$$\mathscr{L}_{\phi}(f) = S_f(f)/2 \tag{2} \label{2}$$

Where:

$S_f(f)$: One-Sided spectral density due to frequency fluctuations

$S_{\phi}(f)$: One-Sided spectral density due to phase fluctuations

$\mathscr{L}_{\phi}(f)$: Two-Sided spectral density due to phase fluctuations

$f$: frequency in Hz

This relationship is because frequency is the time derivative of phase:

$$\omega(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\phi(t)$$

$$f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{d}{dt}\phi(t)$$

Where:

$\omega(t)$ is instantaneous frequency vs time in radians/sec

$f(t) = \frac{\omega(t)}{2\pi}$ is instantaneous frequency vs time in Hz/sec

Phase noise is the spectral density due to phase fluctuations, and the time domain waveform is phase as a function of time (and then complex-conjugate squared to be a power quantity). The spectral density due to frequency fluctuations would similarly be a function of frequency vs time and similarly squared to be a power quantity.   A time domain derivative is a frequency domain product with $2\pi f$ (as indicated by the time derivative property of the Fourier Transform or similarly by multiplying by $s$ in the Laplace Transform).  As a power spectral density this term gets squared resulting in equation \ref{1}.

Phase noise is typically a "small angle" process and that specifically is the condition in which the spectrum that we would measure using a spectrum analyzer would indicate directly a Two-Sided spectral density due to phase fluctuations ($\mathscr{L}_\phi(f)$) if we only have phase noise (no amplitude modulation), resulting in a carrier surrounded by two symmetric sidebands.

This is demonstrated in the graphic below for the case of a sinusoidal phase modulation under a small angle approximation.  The two "sidebands" as phasors rotating in quadrature with the carrier sum together with the carrier to shift the overall phase of the resultant phasor.

[image: Phase Noise]

The angle as shown is exaggerated, but any phase noise -20 dBc and lower below the carrier would be reasonable to be considered "small angle" for purpose of phase noise measurements. The phasor diagram on the left shows both sidebands for the sinusoidal modulation in the time domain as given by Euler's formula:

$$\phi_p\cos(\omega t) = \frac{\phi_p}{2}e^{j\omega t} + \frac{\phi_p}{2}e^{-j\omega t}$$

$e^{j\omega t}$ is a phasor rotating in time with magnitude $1$ and angle $\omega(t)$. For small angles (similarly called narrowband FM), the phase modulation is created by adding the sinusoidal modulation to the normalized carrier in quadrature as:

$$\phi(t) \approx 1 + j\phi_p\cos(\omega t)$$

Thus we see that the phasor diagram on the left side of the graphic represents the two phasors given in the Euler relationship for the cosine modulation, each with a magnitude of $\phi_p/2$ and  added together with the normalized carrier as represented by the phasor with magnitude $1$ and angle $0$ radians. When the cosine is 1 (when $\omega t = 0, 2\pi, 4\pi \ldots$ the angle given by $\phi(t)$ will be at its peak $(\phi_p)$. At this point in time the phasors will form a right triangle with an angle ($\phi$) an an adjacent side of magnitude $\cos(\phi)$ and an opposite side (which is the sum of the two spinning phasors) of magnitude $\sin(\phi)$. For small angle conditions $\cos(\phi) \approx 1$ and $\sin(\phi) \approx \phi$.

Therefore under this small angle condition, for a sinusoidal phase modulation there will be only one pair of significant sidebands each with a relative magnitude to the carrier of $\phi_p/2$. The Two-Sided power spectral density due to phase noise is the power spectrum for this case. Since the phasors represent magnitude quantities, these would each be squared in a power spectrum and therefore in dBc (dB relative to the carrier) each sideband would be given as $-20\log_{10}(\phi_p/2)$ and at the frequency of the phasors' rate of rotation relative to the carrier as depicted in the frequency spectrum plot on the right side of the graphic. For example, if each sideband was $-20$ dB, this would mean that $\phi_p/2 \approx 10^{-20/20} = 0.1$, and $\phi_p \approx 0.2$ radians. To test the validity of the small angle criteria at a sideband level as large as -20 dB, we note that $\sin(0.2) = 0.1987$, and converting this back to the PSD $20\log_10(.1987/2) = -20.06$ dB. Therefore there is only a 0.06 dB error at this relatively larger "small angle" case.

The above demonstrates and derives the "Two Sided" spectral density, and as mentioned is convenient as it is what we would measure directly on a spectrum analyzer (due to the small angle approximation, the magnitude of the sidebands relative to the carrier are directly proportional to phase). Since the upper and lower sidebands are redundant (Hermitian symmetric), we can represent the entire spectrum with a One-Sided power spectral density, in which case we would double the power levels given by the Two-Sided density (adding the powers of both sidebands), leading to equation \ref{2}.

Those familiar with the relationship between frequency modulation and phase modulation may also recognize that $\phi_p$ is the modulation index as $h = \phi_p = \Delta f/f_m$ for FM modulation, from which we can predict all sidebands accurately using Bessel functions of the first kind, which would also confirm the extent of validity for any small angle approximations.

We also see directly in the formula for modulation index how we are similarly multiplying by $f$ when converting from PM modulation to FM modulation: As we saw the peak phase deviation is given by $\phi_p$ and
$\Delta f$ represents the peak frequency deviation with the relationship using the formula for modulation index, where $f_m$ as depicted in the phasor and frequency diagrams above represents the rate of rotation and position of the sideband on the frequency axis:

$$\Delta f = f_m \phi_p$$

Comment: great answer, although I think you might've meant that "frequency is the time derivative of phase" and not the other way around.

Comment: @user67081 yes indeed, thank you!

Comment: thank you for answering , let me check!

Comment: how getting phase noise unit rad^2/Hz?

Comment: @ARATHIP If the magnitude units for phase are in units of radians, then the power units are in units of radians^2. The frequency spectrum of such noise processes don't exist at one specific frequency but are spread out as a density over all frequencies. Thus we describe how much power is in a band of frequencies and the measurement of the density is rad^2/Hz.  If the noise was "white" then the density is constant and we can get the total power over a range of frequencies by multiplying the noise in rad^2/Hz by the bandwidth in Hz.  When not white we do the same thing as an integral.

Comment: ok.  from your answer time domain derivative is a frequency domain product with 2πf (as indicated by the time derivative property of the Fourier Transform or similarly by multiplying by s in the Laplace Transform). As a power spectral density this term gets squared resulting in equation 1. so where is (2pi^2) in equation 1?

Comment: f(t) = 1/(2pi) * d/dt phi(t).    Take the Laplace of that and then evaluate on the j-omega axis. The 2pi cancels if we put it in units of f instead of omega (as is done in S_f(f))

Comment: so after doing cancellation of "2 pi" term we are squaring  to get in terms of power. right?

Comment: @ARATHIP sorry I missed your earlier comment - yes we square to put in units of power.